# Trying to utilize a returned value after calling a different function

Tags: python-3.8

I can't find a way to utilize the return function as in my tkinter GUI I'm unable to return values while using a button press to call on a different function. If you have any ideas on how I can either optimize my method or just a simple solution I'd love to hear.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import re
from tkinter import Tk, filedialog

window=Tk()
window.title('Heater Testing') # Window Title
window.geometry("400x600+20+30")

def smalls():
decimal_values = 221 # just examples
temp_strings = "Ogre"   # just examples
btn4=Button(window, text="Confirm:", fg='Blue', font=("Helvetica", 11), command= Display_ExT)
btn4.place(x=2,y=110)
return decimal_values, temp_strings, False

def Display_ExT(decimal_values, temp_strings, False):
  errorCount = 0
  ExtT = inpu2.get()
  for num, tempName in zip(decimal_values, temp_strings):
     if isinstance(num, float) and abs(num - ExtT) \> False:
         print("Fail:")
         errorCount += 1
     else:
         print("Pass:")

inpu2=Entry(window, text="External Temperature", bd=5, fg='Blue', font=("Helvetica", 16))
inpu2.place(x=75, y=110)

window.mainloop()

pass
```